# Unable to start python process using God

Tags: python, twisted, god

Im using God ([godrb.com](http://godrb.com)) to monitor a twisted framework based application process. In my god file (start_my_app.god) i have

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name='my_app'
  w.start='twistd -y /home/joes/my_app.tac --pidfile /home/joes/my_app.pid'
  w.log='/home/joes/my_app.log'
  w.keepalive
end
```

In my application directory is a file called node.py containing the NodeQS class,and in the `my_app.tac` file im doing

```
from node import NodeQS
```

When i try to start the application using

```
god -c start_my_app.god -D
```

I see the following error in my application log

> exceptions.ImportError: No module named node

I have added /home/joes/my_app to PYTHONPATH, but i still see this error when i run the twistd command using god.

> The above twistd command works if i run it directly

Why is trying to run the same command from god giving me an import error ?

Comment: This should be cause by a bad `PYTHONPATH`. The most easy way to fix that would be to change the working directory first. Try to add `cd /home/joes;` before the real command.

Comment: Thanks a lot Klaus D. !! :). Adding the cd as u suggested fixed it. Please add it as an answer, so that i can mark it as accepted :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a Python script with its full path, the `PATHONPATH` is set to the current working directory. This path is then used as the base to import the packages and modules.

To make that the `PYTHONPATH` reflects your project directory, you `cd` there first. You can add the command to do so to the `.start` value:

```
God.watch do |w|
  w.name='my_app'
  w.start='cd /home/joes; twistd -y /home/joes/my_app.tac --pidfile /home/joes/my_app.pid'
  w.log='/home/joes/my_app.log'
  w.keepalive
end
```